# Schedule import csv to SQL Server 2014 Express edition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

Is there a way to have a `.csv` or `.txt` imported into SQL Server automatically?

I know how to do it manually using Date import & Export tool. But is it possible to do it automatically?

Comment: You can schedule a job -- typically through SQL Server Agent -- to import a table.

Comment: But In SQL express edition, SQL server agent wont work

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler then?

Comment: Okay..But how to do it?

Comment: [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2019698/how-to-schedule-and-automate-backups-of-sql-server-databases-in-sql-se) is a way to schedule backups. Apply the same approach to your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Windows Task Scheduler](https://windowsreport.com/schedule-tasks-windows-10/) to run [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017) commands automatically. The command that will be run automatically will import your csv file using bulk copy program (bcp) utility. It can import or export data from/to files. For example to import a csv file to a table in SQL Server, you can use command like this:

```
bcp.exe dbo.MyTable in "C:\Some Folder\Data.csv" -s MYPC\SQLEXPRESS -d MyDatabase -U LoginName -P StrongP@ssw0rd
```

Where:

- `dbo.MyTable` is the schema and table name, where data should be imported.
- `in` tells the direction (put data **in** the database, or get data **out** of it).
- `"C:\Some Folder\Data.csv"` is the name and path to the file holding the data to be imported.
- `MYPC\SQLEXPRESS` is the computer and SQL Server instance name.
- `MyDatabase` is the name of the database, where `dbo.MyTable` is.
- `LoginName` and `StronP@ssw0rd` are the credentials to be used to connect to the server (or `-E` instead of `-U` and `-P` to connect using Windows Authentication).

Then create a new scheduled task (`Start` -> `Task Scheduler` -> `Create Basic Task`) and set a schedule according your requirements (e.g. daily at 3:00 AM) to run the command above.

Comment: Hello..thanks for your valuable input. Do I need to create a .bat file for the above cmd in order to setup task scheduler...I am kind of new to this topic...

Comment: No, you don't need `bat` or `cmd` file (but you can do it this way, though). Just enter all command line parameters in the optional arguments field in the wizard.

Comment: Is it possible to schedule import based on the files in the particular folder?Also If the particular files is imported, It should be moved to another folder For example, If the import was successful, It should go into Success folder or else into Error folder..

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But in this case I will suggest to write a PowerShell script to do this job, and schedule execution of this script.

Answer (score 0):

To automate the process of importing CSV files into SQL Server 2014 Express Edition, you might consider using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) to create a package that performs the import operation.

Another option is to write a script using PowerShell or another scripting language that utilizes the SQL Server bulk insert command, and then schedule this script to run at specific intervals using Windows Task Scheduler.

Unfortunately, SQL Server Express Edition has limitations, such as the lack of SQL Agent, which restricts direct scheduling within SQL Server.