# Having a data upload get "picked up" by SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, file, refresh

I need to transfer some data over to another location so that it can get "refreshed" in their database system (SQL Server).

I'm a little unfamiliar with this, is SQL server able to refresh its own internal tables based on anything? For instance is it able to recreate/refresh tables based on the contents of .CSV files? Or would I need to move the data over in the form of a small Access database with tables or something similar?

What is the "correct" way to do something like this where you need to refresh the data of another server based on the content you have somewhere else?

Comment: Use SSIS - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Depending on how visible the other server is, you could consider log shipping or database mirroring, possibly even availalability groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be to use SSIS as Brad suggested.

But if you are not familiar with SSIS packages then you can opt for simple sql server job to upload data from csv files periodically. Please have a look in below links:

[Schedule import csv to SQL Server 2014 Express edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853402/schedule-import-csv-to-sql-server-2014-express-edition)

https://answers.laserfiche.com/questions/74591/Auto-Import-csv-into-SQL-Table

Comment: Hope your have solved the problem. Best wishes.